# Are there visualisations of the Kerma state along with other Nile Valley civilizations?

Tags: ancient-history, maps

Wikipedia describes [the Kerma state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kerma_culture) as existing contemporaneously with Middle Kingdom Egypt, from approx 2500 BC to 1500 BC. Yet, the article on the Kerma doesn't illustrate the Kermanese (?) sphere of influence or major cities (archaeological sites) within its own context or within the Nile Valley overall.

The Wikipedia article (and other sources, including a podcast on Sudanese history) mention that the Kermanese influence probably spread from the Third to the Sixth Cataracts. At the same time, most of the article also mentions how recent our understanding of the culture is—possibly a reason why not many maps have been drawn with the Kerma settlements.

[Wikipedia on Old Kingdom Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Kingdom_of_Egypt) highlights a settlement at Kerma but doesn't present any information on how far their influence spread (or where the boundary with the Old Kingdom would have been). [Wikipedia on Middle Kingdom Egypt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Middle_Kingdom_of_Egypt) doesn't show a neighbouring state to the south.

[Many](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Flaurenkfoster.wordpress.com%2Ftag%2Fkerma%2F&psig=AOvVaw35-T5h-PyOddGCYk-FNvoj&ust=1598884920113000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAIQjRxqFwoTCMDSmdGUw-sCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAP) maps seem to show [Kush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Kush), a later reincarnation of Kerma (slightly overemphasised), but it's not clear that the centers of population or, indeed, influence would have been in the same locations.

When searching for this on Google Image search, [I found this map](https://oi.uchicago.edu/museum-exhibits/nubia/ancient-nubia-c-group%E2%80%93pan-grave%E2%80%93kerma-2400%E2%80%931550-bc) but it doesn't note the specific time or year (and it doesn't highlight Egyptian spheres of power at the same time):

[image]

I found [this article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/259479951_Reach-scale_river_dynamics_moderate_the_impact_of_rapid_Holocene_climate_change_on_floodwater_farming_in_the_desert_Nile) which included a map of Kerma sites though there are so many of them I'm not sure all are settlements or what relevance they may have had (plus there's no reference to neighbouring kingdoms):

[image]

Lastly, I also found [this incredibly informative post](https://thinkafrica.net/the-kingdom-of-kerma-2500-1500-bc/) with two good maps, but the focus is on Egypt though with a helpful amount of information on Nubia. Yet, even these don't really denote a sphere of influence for Kerma or where its other neighbours were:

[image]
[image]

---

**In other words, there are plenty of maps which focus on Egypt but not as much on the other Nile Valley civilizations, including Kerma. Does anyone know of a visualization which would illustrate Kerma along with the Egyptian realm, their main settlements, and other relevant civilizations?**

Comment: I suspect the answer is probably not.  If I recall correctly, we don't have written sources for Kerma, and determining the limits of any ancient civilisation based solely on its material culture is always going to be problematic, their sphere of influence even more so.

Comment: @sempaiscuba: I suspect you are correct. All of my world history atlases are too old to include them. My 2008 atlas doesn't even have the city of Kerma on it for Old/Middle Kingdom Egyptian maps. :/ I would be more surprised if something released these days didn't include them at all...

Comment: There's a 2015 article [Human occupations and environmental changes in the Nile valley
during the Holocene: The case of Kerma in Upper Nubia (northern
Sudan)](https://bit.ly/3pM0HxR) which may be of interest to you.

Comment: Try [this](https://d1wqtxts1xzle7.cloudfront.net/51325341/QSR_15_KERMA.pdf?1484262435=&response-content-disposition=inline%3B+filename%3DHuman_occupations_and_environmental_chan.pdf&Expires=1605839547&Signature=BvPfPmisK7FA2OaT5qy9ZmB2Cm0G3QgRvpRC0bOsTEXvZLZdcDKW2zNv1~U4tSmOCFBT-PQBAGCG9eWllZcqZ4MdBudTO0laImQHjxPRxGzI2mbPQFu0iPDnUcq~IMocsr7CrhY5ivku3~Qx-6lgCpJmXcKYIa7vPCWydssA6B6xjzaQp1zOgl2~0w9I6u7CneFnJXOcSHwwnAIVR~gk0UZOxk9kASv73YpRqG75rMbHcmGSZJAreoFaHJGgSIpiu390K3AQVGrCSKXHVADp-vbpD3VSH7n7yAex33v6qha-HMP2vLP5GvZ4TW-VXGQ4UOGTaLjsFhb91QvSiva0LA__&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLOHF5GGSLRBV4ZA)

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. I just tested the second link and it works fine for me. Maybe it's restricted in your location?

Comment: Could be! Yeah, it's not that the link is broken but it does say "Access restricted."